# ng-repeat + ng-switch: how to use correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Premise: I've seen several similar questions. But I can't really figure out how to solve my doubt.

I have an array of objects:

```
$scope.messages = [obj1, obj2, ...];
```

where each object has the following structure:

```
{
   id: <int>,
   printOnlyFirst: <boolean>,
   text1: <string>,
   text2: <string>
}
```

where text1 / text2 are conditionally printed (in real time through **track by**) according to **printOnlyFirst**.

```
<div id="container">
    <div ng-switch="printOnlyFirst" ng-repeat="message in messages track by message.id">
        <div ng-switch-when="true" class="text1"> <!-- case 1 -->
            {{message.text1}
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="false" class="text2"> <!-- case 2 -->
            {{message.text2}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this code is fine.

However I noticed that

```
<div ng-switch="printOnlyFirst" ng-repeat="message in messages track by message.id">
```

is printed for each single element of the ng-repeat loop, together with it's content (either case 1 or 2).

Is this normal?
Is there a better solution to avoid such DOM overhead?

Comment: Should be `ng-switch="message.printOnlyFirst"` but I would disagree with the usage of `ng-switch` in this case. If `printOnlyFirst` is true then only `text1` is shown, but if false then does it show both `text` and `text2` or just `text1`?

Comment: either text1 or 2. not both.
actually this is just an example. what is shown is an element of an array, rather than a string or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-:

> Directives with greater numerical `priority` are compiled first.

[`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) executes at priority 1200 while [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) executes at priority 1000, which isn't the order you need.

You'll have to use a nested component (a `div` for example):

```html
<div id="container">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages track by message.id">
        <div ng-switch="message.printOnlyFirst">
            <div ng-switch-when="true" class="text1"> <!-- case 1 -->
                {{message.text1}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="false" class="text2"> <!-- case 2 -->
                {{message.text2}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to switch on `message.printOnlyFirst` rather than `printOnlyFirst`.

Comment: thank you.
it works.
however <div ng-repeat="message in messages track by message.id" class="ng-scope"> is printed N times (not much differently than before)
is this normal?

Comment: @dragonmnl Yes, `ngRepeat` repeats the DOM element it is defined on as many times as asked.